# C++'s std::string pools, debug builds? std::string and valgrind problems

Tags: c++, string, gcc, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a problem with many valgrind warnings about possible memory leaks in std::string, like this one:

```
120 bytes in 4 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4,192 of 4,687
    at 0x4A06819: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:230)
    by 0x383B89B8B0: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
    by 0x383B89C3B4: (within /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
    by 0x383B89C4A9: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
```

I'm wondering:

- does std::string (GCC 4.1.2) use any memory pools?
- if so, is there any way to disable the pools (in form of a debug build etc.)?

Answer (score 6):

Check the [FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.memory_leaks). There is a section about *“Memory leaks” in containers*. You should

- check your version of Valgrind
- use a debug build of your program (and un-optimized)
- and define `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW` if necessary.  (This is an environment variable that affects your program's runtime behavior, not a compile-time `#define` as you might expect.)

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a false positive.  This can be suppressed as described in the [manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html)

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, many STL allocators implement some kind of retention of memory. IE they do not release the memory allocated right away, but keep it around and reuse it. I certainly had many false positives in valgrind coming from memory allocated by my STL implementation.

The best way I have found to deal with the problem is (simply) to use the suppression file.

Answer (score 1):

120 bytes are not enough for the pool. [Do you exit() from your program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901322/valgrind-report-memory-leak-when-assign-a-value-to-a-string)

Comment: No, no exit(). So why is the memory possibly lost if there is no pool?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and for me, it was because I was linking with a development version of a library, but my test code was picking up the older system-installed version.  The changes were subtle enough that it would link and run without any apparent problems, but Valgrind would detect weird leaks.  Using `ldd` in place of `valgrind` confirmed that it was picking up the wrong library file.  Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly fixed it, although the correct solution is to increment the library version as it's obviously not backwards compatible any more if you get this happening.

I have also seen this problem when an object hasn't been destroyed properly, such as a class with `virtual` functions missing a `virtual` destructor.  When the class is put into a pointer-to-base-class and then destroyed, only the base class destructor runs, leaking anything allocated in the derived classes, like `std::string` instances in your example.  The hint here was to check which class was using the leaked `string`, and follow the class hierarchy back to the base class and confirm it has an explicit `virtual` destructor, even an empty one.  I was assuming they were implicit if there are `virtual` functions in a class but apparently not, and GCC doesn't warn you about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my program terminated due to an uncaught exception.  Apparently the handler for uncaught exceptions does not clean everything up.