# Thread termination with pthread_exit followed by return - Strange example

Tags: c, multithreading, return, pthreads, pthread-exit

I found [this example](https://books.google.it/books?id=21YsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=difference%20between%20pthread_exit(NULL)%20and%20return%20NULL&source=bl&ots=fhjtdtiFv8&sig=ACfU3U215ztj486BzcebHbe9rH6CWP6RqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC7MjZ-qjqAhUiyKYKHU9zAMgQ6AEwDHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=difference%20between%20pthread_exit(NULL)%20and%20return%20NULL&f=false); here the two threads threadDefault and threadCustomized are terminated by using pthread_exit followed by return. Why did the author write both instructions?

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844678/pthread-exit-vs-return

Comment: Hello @Ted thank you for your suggestion. In the high score reply the OP used only pthread_exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mohith Reddy's answer is correct but misses the point. Of course the return statement is never executed since `pthread_exit` doesn't return, but it's there to suppress warnings from the compiler in case it's not aware that `pthread_exit` doesn't return.

Comment: Yes that should be it! Even I am remembering now inserting a ``return`` myself after ``pthread_exit`` to suppress the compiler warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @R...GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Could you do an example showing the warning you're talking about please?

Answer (score 1):

From the `pthread_exit()` man page:

**RETURN VALUE**

> This function does not return to the caller.

**ERRORS**

> This function always succeeds.

**NOTES**

> Performing a return from the start function of any thread other than the main thread results in an implicit call to `pthread_exit()`, using the function's return value as the thread's exit status.

The above all suggests that `pthread_exit();` and `return NULL;` are redundant when both are called together.

Comment: Hi @MohithReddy the strange thing is that, after the execution of the pthread_exit, the return should not be executed because the pthread_exit terminates the thread.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Yes, that is how it should happen. Is ``return`` getting called after ``pthread_exit()``? If yes, how are you making sure? Sometimes IDE may not be following the source code well.