# std::string memory leak

Tags: c++, string, valgrind, std

I've got this class `AppController` and the function `connectPlayer`:

```
/* AppController.h */
    class AppController
    {
          // Some other declarations ...
      private:
            static const string TAG;
    };

/* AppController.cpp */

#include "AppController.h"
const string AppController::TAG = "AppController";

AppController::AppController() {
    /* some code here...*/
}

void AppController::connectPlayer() {
    std::string port;
    std::string host;
    port = CM->getMenu()->getData("PORT");
    host = CM->getMenu()->getData("HOST");
    this->setState("Connecting...");
    Logger::info(TAG, "Port: " + port);
    Logger::info(TAG, "Host: " + host);
}
```

And when I execute the program, I get this from valgrind:

```
==7848== 25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 160 of 671
==7848==    at 0x402842F: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==7848==    by 0x4210A83: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==7848==    by 0x4212CF7: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==7848==    by 0x4212E65: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==7848==    by 0x8080501: AppController::connectPlayer() (in /home/maine/Escritorio/taller7542/UltimaVersion/src/main)
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `AppController::TAG` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz, it's just the name of the class. I use it to write in a Logger the important events that happen during the execution of the program.

Comment: Having _non-POD_ objects of static duration (like your `AppController::TAG` which is a `std::string`) may not be good thing. You may want to try use a POD like a simple `const char []` instead. See also [this section from Google's C++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Static_and_Global_Variables).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have `std::string` objects in global scope: `AppController::TAG`.

When application finished in not very normal way you've got these kind of valgrind errors for global objects. Probably nothing to worry.

If you (cannot/don't want to) change your program - read this doc: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress to get rid of this very error.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, valgrind gives false positives. This means that even if valgrind says you lose memory, actually you don't.

The only thing to worry about is when you call the `exit()` function, as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687539/c-valgrind-possible-leaks-on-stl-string) question.

If you do not want to see these warnings any more, you can create a **suppressions file** giving valgrind some information on which errors to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

I had seen this issue once when I had a string in a class in global scope. Valgrind kept complaining that I was leaking memory. I just "deleted" the object at exit and the error was gone.