# Valgrind memory leak with std::string in std::map

Tags: c++, valgrind, stdstring, stdmap

Here is the output from Valgrind:

```
==6519==    at 0x4C25885: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:319)
==6519==    by 0x4EE65D8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
==6519==    by 0x4EE7CE0: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (basic_string.tcc:138)
==6519==    by 0x4EE80F7: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (basic_string.h:1725)
==6519==    by 0x41C399: pilInpOpts::pilInpOpts() (pilInpOpts.cpp:12)
==6519==    by 0x403A55: main (main.cpp:32)
```

This same error is repeated for every entry in the map.

main.cpp line 32 is:

```
    pilInpOpts input;
```

Line 12 of the pilInpOpts is part of the constructor:

```
#include "pilInpOpts.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


pilInpOpts::pilInpOpts() 
{
// create the map of options, put in alphabetical order to ease sorting
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("bforce",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("coef",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("dualjet",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("flow",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("gforce",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("gpress",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("matlab",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("model",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("out_shade",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("out_shade_file",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("press",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("proc",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("shade",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("summary",false));
piloptmap.insert(std::pair<std::string, bool>("trans",false));
// need to define the default filepaths, this is needed because they are optional
platpath = "";
vehpath = "";
apppath = "";
dockpath = "";
};
```

I found some posts in SO which said Valgrind may produce false positives.  For example: [std::string memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001784/c-stdstring-memory-leak)

Is this a false positive since std::string has all the constructors etc it needs to do this?  Or should I change to use C character arrays in the map?

Comment: Could you add information about the compiler, compilation flags, platform, and version of valgrind? I attempted to create a minimal example based on your description, but in this instance valgrind reported no memory errors at all. Perhaps you could reduce your problem to a minimal, self-contained example that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the probable reasons of this behavior may be memory pooling in C++ standard library implementation.

From [Valgrind faq](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports):

> Memory for quite a number of destructed objects is not immediately
>   freed and given back to the OS, but kept in the pool(s) for later
>   re-use. The fact that the pools are not freed at the exit of the
>   program cause Valgrind to report this memory as still reachable. The
>   behaviour not to free pools at the exit could be called a bug of the
>   library though.

You can set `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW` environment variable before running your app to force STL to free memory as soon as possible.

See also these links on details of libstdc++ memory allocator implementation:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.memory_leaks
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html#debug.memory

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues with strings, and if I recall correctly, I was able to get rid of the errors by specifically implementing a destructor for the container class. For a map, you'll need to make an iterator, then explicitly delete the elements of iterator->first and iterator->second inside a loop for the size of the map.

Comment: If you absolutely have to fix the error (as was my case, since the code was being used for passoff in one of my classes and required 0 memory leaks from Valgrind), this is the only way that I've found to date to fix this issue.