# google-perftools shows that std::string::_Rep::_S_create is using 20gb of memory

Tags: c++, memory

I am profiling my program using Google Perf tools and find that I am running out of memory on std::string::_Rep::_S_create.  Perf tools shows 20gb in use:

```
20526.0  92.1%  92.1%  20526.0  92.1% std::string::_Rep::_S_create
```

Does anyone know what this could be?  So far I've found:

1. Suggestions that the std::string allocator could be grabbing large chunks of memory to avoid calling new.
2. std::string destructor does not get called due to exit() or some such call.  So far I have not found any evidence of this in my program.

Any other ideas about how I could track this down?

Thanks.

---

Edit:

Via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901322/valgrind-report-memory-leak-when-assign-a-value-to-a-string) I moved libstdc++ to shared and enabled GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW and that seems to have fixed the problem. It's still unclear to me why the issue occurred in the first place though.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Maybe you have a lot of really big strings?

Comment: This looks like the output of the [`tcmalloc` heap-profiler](https://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heapprofile.html) read by `pprof --text`. If so, `pprof --gv` will give you the call-graph view. Combine that with the periodic heap allocation dumps to figure out when and where this happened.

Comment: This is on a remote linux box.  Can I somehow view the graphical display?  When I try it complains that it can't open the graphical display.

Comment: You can dump the call-graph to a format of your choice : `pprof --pdf`, for example, writes the `pdf` output to `stdio`. Look at `pprof --help` for more file formats.