# Copy bytes to string without memory leak in C++

Tags: c++, valgrind

How to copy memory bytes to a string variable assigned to a class object **with memory leak**? The memory holds bytes to be copied (not ends with '\0'), but will be freed later.

The example code is below, and Valgrind all reports memory leak for three cases.

**Update**:
I forget to mention the string variable will be used by another class object.

```
class Bar
{
   string name;

   ~Bar()
   {
     // should we manually free name's buffer in Bar destructor?    
     // name's buffer is possibly on heap, see Valgrind message
   }
}

void foo(unsigned char *data, uint32 len, Bar *bar)
{
   string str;
   
   // case1, direct conversion
   str = string((char *)data);  
   
   // case2, allocate a new buffer and then copy
   unsigned char *p;            
   p = new unsigned char [len];
   memcpy(p, data, len);
   str = string(char *)p);
   delete[] p;

   // case3, use assign
   str.assign(data, len);   

   // memory leak
   bar->name = str;   
   
}
```

Valgrind message:

```
==65558== 96 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 55 of 128
==65558==    at 0x10012B532: malloc (in /usr/local/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==65558==    by 0x1006C3DE0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib)
==65558==    by 0x10063531B: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__grow_by_and_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==65558==    by 0x100634E75: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::assign(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
```

Thank you.

Comment: my guess is that you allocated the argument data on the heap before calling this function and have not freed it. This code is fine (as long as data is 0 terminated)

Comment: Is the data guaranteed to be '\0' terminated? Also don't use "C" style casts like (char *), but if you must use static_cast<char*>(data); And any solution with new/delete should be considered last (new/delete are no longer the recommended solution in C++)

Comment: @pm100 thanks.  data is a large memory chunk and it does not end with '\0'.

Comment: If it's not null terminated, you must use the provided len argument. std::string has a constructor for that.

Comment: well not ending with 0 makes case1 bad then, that will copy until it hits 0.

Comment: valgrind will point at the line where the leaked allocation was made, what is it pointing at? Also note that the C++ runtime string library doesnt release string memory back to the heap. So maybe not a real leak. You can tell GCC to have an honest string heap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901322/valgrind-reports-memory-leak-when-assigning-a-value-to-a-string

Comment: I assume you meant to ask how to copy memory bytes **without** a memory leak, i.e. that the first sentence in the question has an error and isn't asking how to create a memory leak?

Comment: The most important attribute you've is the `length` information of the given buffer. You should definitely use it under any condition. Don't rely on the `null` termination method.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to construct a `std::string` from unterminated data is to use the constructor that takes both a pointer and a length:

```
string str(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), len);
```

Once you've done that, you can pass around `str` however you wish without having to worry about leaking memory (`str` will have made its own internal copy of the data and will take care not to leak it).